# Bash - Concatenating Variable on to Path

Tags: linux, bash

Currently, I have a bash script that will untar a file in my root directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar xvf ~/some-file.tar
```

This works without problems. Now, I would like to change this so I can specify the path to the file in a pre-defined variable like such:

```
#!/bin/bash
p="~"
tar xvf $p/some-file.tar
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
tar: ~/some-file.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

The path to the file seems to be correct, however, are there some hidden characters causing this to fail? What is the proper way to concatenate a variable and a path without storing both in string variables (if there is one)?

Comment: This was simply an example, the reason I would like to store the path in a variable is because it may change based on how the script is run

Comment: But the tilde is the root of the problem...

Comment: Yes, I did not realize this when I posted

Comment: Always test the simplest thing ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tilde expansion doesn't work when inside a variable. You can use the `$HOME` variable instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
p=$HOME
tar xvf "$p/some_file.tar"
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I did not realize that the error was due to the tilde. Thanks!

Comment: One question however: I plan to take the path as a command line option in my script. How do I handle the `~` if the user decides to enter it?

Comment: just a side note: `~` only works when it's the first char of the argument with no quote. for example, `echo abc=~` will print literally.

Comment: @kshah You don't need to handle it. It will be interpreted by the shell when the user types it in his terminal.

Comment: @kshah it's better for you to delegate to other tool to make your life easier, like python, have a look at `os.path.expanduser`. too naive solution won't work, for example, tilde expansion support user name suffix: `~user1` should expand to home folder of `user1`.